# How to make python import module along with folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently I have the following directory

```
my_epic_module
-> .gitignore
-> my_epic_module.py
main.py
```

When I try to import `my_epic_module.py` from `main.py` I do the following

```
# the following does not work
import my_epic_module
my_epic_module.bar("foo")

# the following works
from my_epic_module import my_epic_module
my_epic_module.bar("foo")
```

How do I make it so that I can just import it "normally" like the top first example? Do I need to add an `__init__.py`? If so what do I need to put into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python `module` is a file. a folder with `__init__.py` is a package. Both of them can be used with `import` statement.

if you want to use `import my_epic_module`, you have serval way to achieve it.

put `my_epic_module.py` on the top folder

OR

add `__init__.py` to `my_epic_module` folder and add `from .my_epic_module import *` to `__init__.py` file

OR

add `my_epic_module` folder to `sys.path`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to add `__init__.py` file in your folder.

No need to write anything into `__init__.py` file. 
Just keep it in you folder. It makes your folder like a package then you can import it.